# Sum Issue with multiple fields in mysql select query

Tags: mysql, select, sum, union

I have two tables rentals and sales.There is a field status.If status=1 is unpublish,status=2 is publish and status=3 is pending.

I want to find sum of all publish,unpublish and pending in rentals and sales for agents.

Here is what i tried but it give me wrong data

```
select sum(publish1) publish, sum(unpublish1) unpublish, sum(pending1) pending, agent_id,status from ( 

select agent_id,status, count(*) as publish1, 0 unpublish1, 0 pending1 from rentals where status = 2  GROUP BY agent_id 

union all select agent_id,status, 0 publish1, count(*) as unpublish1, 0 pending1 from rentals where status = 1  GROUP BY agent_id 

union all select agent_id,status, 0 publish1, 0 pending1, count(*) as pending1 from rentals where status = 3 GROUP BY agent_id 

union all select agent_id,status, count(*) as publish1, 0 unpublish1, 0 pending1 from sales where status = 2  GROUP BY agent_id 

union all select agent_id,status, 0 publish1, count(*) as unpublish1, 0 pending1 from sales where status = 1 GROUP BY agent_id 

union all select agent_id,status, 0 publish1, 0 pending1, count(*) as pending1 from sales where status = 3  GROUP BY agent_id ) s GROUP BY agent_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description of the problem, your query looks right.  Here is another way of writing the query.  It just does the aggregation before the `union`:

```
select agent_id,
       sum(case when status = 2 then val else 0 end) as publish,
       sum(case when status = 1 then val else 0 end) as unpublish,
       sum(case when status = 3 then val end) as pending
from ((select status, agent_id, status, count(*) as val
       from rentals
       where status in (2, 1, 3)
       group by status, agent_id 
      ) union all
      (select status, agent_id, count(*) as val
       from sales
       where status in (2, 1, 3)
       group by status, agent_id
      )
     ) t
group by agent_id;
```